# ¿Como configurar un string dinamico?

Tags: c, string

Estoy intentando hacer un porgrama que creo que debe ser simple. Quiero pedir una palabra y almacenarla en un vector con su tamaño justo (mas `\n` logicamente). Para ello el programa solicita al usuario que escriba una palabra finalizada por un punto (`.`). A continuacion, lee letra a letra de teclado y va almacenando las letras de un vector que vas creando dinamicamente a medida que vaya leyendo los caracteres.

```
 int main(){
   int i = 0;
   char *cad = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
   char c;

   printf("Introduce una palabra(. para terminar): ");
   
   while(c != '.'){
       //Leer caracter a caracter
       cad[i] = c;
       i++;
       realloc(cad, i*sizeof(char));
   }
   cad[i] = '\0';

   return 0;
 }
```

He hecho esto, que no se si está muy bien, pero no se como hacer que lea precisamente caracter a caracter.

Answer (score 0):

> He hecho esto, que no se si está muy bien

A grandes rasgos sí, sería una forma de conseguir tu objetivo.

No obstante nota que tu solución **no funciona**

`realloc` **no modifica** `cad`, sino que devuelve un puntero con la nueva posición de la memoria... y tu no estás recuperando esa posición:

```
cad = realloc(cad, i * sizeof(char));
```

Por otro lado, suponte que el sistema se queda sin memoria... lo que sucede entonces es que `realloc` devolverá un puntero nulo... hay que tener en cuenta esta situación:

```
char * ptr = realloc( cad, i * sizeof(char));
if( ptr == 0 )
{
  // Te has quedado sin memoria
  exit(1);
}
else
{
  cad = ptr;
}
```

Por otro lado, nota que el tamaño de la reserva es insuficiente:

```
int i = 0;
char *cad = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

while(c != '.'){
    //Leer caracter a caracter
    cad[i] = c;
    i++;
    realloc(cad, i*sizeof(char));
}
```

Según tu algoritmo, sucederá lo siguiente:

- i=0
- hacemos una reserva para almacenar hasta 1 caracter
- escribimos el primer caracter que introduce el usuario
- incrementamos i -> 0++ = 1
- llamamos a realloc, el tamaño de la nueva reserva es 1 ... luego no hace nada
- pedimos un segundo caracter al usuario
- introducimos el caracter en el array ... ups no entra

El valor de la reseva tiene que ser una unidad superior al valor dado para `i`:

```
realloc(cad, (i+1)*sizeof(char));
```

> no entiendo finalmente como quedaría el resultado

Me he centrado en el uso que haces de `realloc`, luego simplemente tienes que sustituir la llamada a realloc por el código que voy poniendo en la respuesta:

```
while(c != '.'){
    //Leer caracter a caracter
    cad[i] = c;
    i++;

    // realloc(cad, i*sizeof(char));
    char * ptr = realloc(cad, (i+1)*sizeof(char));
    if( ptr == 0 )
    {
      // Te has quedado sin memoria
      exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
      cad = ptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Tienes que llamar a realloc una última vez:* No, no es necesario. Hay espacio para el character que se está leyendo en la próxima iteración, y hay espacio per el `\0` si no hay la próxima iteración.

Comment: @n.m.ןoṵɐdsǝᴉɯɐןƃǝɹɹɐ cierto, escribí esa parte demasiado rápido

Comment: no entiendo finalmente como quedaría el resultado :(